# How to set SOLR EdgeNgrams Exception?

Tags: solr, filter

I come here to ask a question about SOLR.

I have a EdgeNgramTokenFilter that act as expected for most of the words in indexing, excepted for some that are causing some trouble.

For example, the term "wordpress" is reduce by the EdgeNgram into "word". But i don't want that, to see wordpress result in my "word" search.

**Is there a way to have exception on my filter, so wordpress doesn't get reduce to "word", or any other tricks to dodge that problem?**

I have a solution in mind to increase  minimal word size of my ngram, but i would like to avoid doing so.

Thanks in advance for your answer, and sorry if my english is hard to read.

Comment: Use multiple fields for different uses. EdgeNGrams are usually used to provide type-ahead or similar functionality. Exactly what are you trying to make the field do?

Comment: i didn't make the code myself, so i can just guess it from what i've been told.

The field is here, so that some search, like "manager" matches with "management" and so on with other kind of word.

At first, it was also use for type ahead, but the function was removed

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for stemming, not ngramming.

Comment: Oh, i'll look at that Asap. 
while you pass, mind to share any useful link for stemming, kind stranger ?